# Implementing Many to Many, Subforms, Checkboxes in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba

Person
    Person_Pet
    Pet

I need to make a data entry form.  Let's say we have a table called Person and that has the appropriate fields in it.  On my form I need to allow the user to select from (one or many) checkboxes that represent all the possible pets they could have (fixed list of items: dog, serval, llama, jackalope, emu, dragon, spider...).

For the form, there needs to be one checkbox to represent each possible choice. If that person does have a pet dog then that checkbox needs to be true and if they don't have a dog it needs to be false (I guess I'm stating the obvious because I got stuck trying to do this as a subform with the "many to many" and displaying "false" valued things.  They can chose more than one.

Eventually I need to make a new form or reuse the data entry form for modificiations, etc.

Is this a subform?  I have a Person table, Pet table, Person_Pet (id/joining) table.  I'm trying to go at all this with VBA but I think I've picked the hard way, however, it isn't too late to change directions.

edit:
what if i was starting with this?  it would result in something that gave me a list of all possible pets and if the p.personid was null then the checkbox is not checked.  if it is not null then it is checked.  is this possible?  (excuse the formatting, access sql writer doesn't know what a tab is apparently and excuse sytanx errors because i had to do a quick find and replace for table names)

```
select pet.*, p.personid
from pet pet 
left outer join
(select pi.petID, pi.personid
from    person,
        pet_person pi,
        pet 
where   person.id = pi.personID and
        pet.id = pi.petID) as p
on p.petID = pet.id
```

edit:

okay.  there's a huge answer down there.  i solved it, too.  i haven't looked at your answer but i will in a lil bit.  here's my answer...  (no subform, just all on the main form, "person" form)

1. make checkboxes... and name them chk1, chk2, chk3... and so on.
2. make sure they correspond to appropriate fields in my lil pet table.... so dog = chk1, serval = chk2... stuff
3. do this vba (and call function from Form_Current() and pass it me.id):

Function update_checkboxes(issueID As Variant)
    Dim query As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim a As String

```
If Not IsNull(issueID) Then
    query = "SELECT iif(joined.issueid is null, 0, 1) as binval, payer.* " & _
            "FROM payer AS payer LEFT JOIN (select ri.issueid, ri.payerid " & _
                    "from  issue i, payer r, payer_issue ri " & _
                    "where i.id = ri.issueid and r.id = ri.payerid and ri.issueid = " & issueID & _
                    ")  AS joined ON joined.payerid = payer.id;"
Else
    query = "select 0 as binval, payer.* from payer"
End If

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(query)
rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
    s = rs.Fields("CorrespondingChkboxNumber")
    Me.Controls("chk" & s).Value = rs.Fields("binval")
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
End Function
```

Yeah.  that copy paste code format stackoverflow thing is hating on me.  sorry.  UM.  issue = person, payer = pet.  i know the corresponding check box thing isn't idea, i'm going to have to search/check a string field but this shows the concept of what i think i might end up using unless...................

**Follow up question:  are there any serious time constraints issues/consequences/sumthing to running these vba queries each time the record is changed?**

btw.  fyi.  the desire to show the possible answers with selected answers is because sometimes what things aren't is equally important as what things are.  some areas/counties/municipalities won't allow pitbulls.  the whole state of california apparently outlaws ferrets.  i do have a pitbull.  i do not have a ferret.  we all only wish we had pet dragons to train.  all of these are on the no-no pet list in some areas so.... both these things need to be displayed.  a listbox could do it but i feel it's a little awkward looking.  by visibly listing all my possible pets, i know which ones raise flags. although in the end it only truly matters what i do have....... still.  but obviously i'm not making a cute little access database for people and pets and where they can live.

Comment: regarding your Follow Up: When you move from one dataset to another there is so much going on behind the scenes that this little vbacode doesn't make any difference. The really time-consuming part would be the SQL - and that scales well (i.e. it doesn't take longer if you have more datasets in pet_person) - and running through the whole petlistbox would only be a problem if there were thousands of datasets in the pet-table which would pose other problems with your design first;)

Comment: another thought: some people take the time to think about your questions, make - hopefully - valuable contributions and sometimes help you big time for free. You can show them respect in edititng your question wehen you dont get it right the first time - or even better: write it in you local editor and paste it in when you have it... Just a remark - no offense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With VBA you can use the following code. There are two options:

1. with the 'native' Access Listbox:    this shows your selection as
   highlighted lines in a conventional listbox

   chose multiselect=1 (Single) in the listboxes property/all
   sheet and modify the below code -> uncvomment the commented lines
   and    comment the ones above instead
2. with the MSForms.Listbox (chose activeX insert in Formcreation)
   here you get the checkboxes you wanted.

   chose Multiselect:multi and ListStyle:option. Here there is no    click event, so I chose the Exit event instead. I
   havent encountered    any problems so far, but methodically a click
   event would be nicer.

And here's the code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim pPetListBox As MSForms.ListBox

Private Sub FillPetListbox() 
  pPetListBox.Clear
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from pet order by id")
  While Not rst.EOF
    pPetListBox.AddItem rst!ID
    pPetListBox.List(pPetListBox.ListCount - 1, 1) = rst!petname
    rst.MoveNext
  Wend
  rst.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim indx As Long
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from person_pet where personid=" & Me.ID)
  For indx = 0 To pPetListBox.ListCount - 1
    rst.FindFirst "petID = " & pPetListBox.Column(0, indx)
'    rst.FindFirst "petID = " & petList.ItemData(indx)
    pPetListBox.Selected(indx) = Not rst.NoMatch
  Next
  rst.Close
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateLinkTable()
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim indx As Long
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from person_pet where personid=" & Me.ID)
  indx = pPetListBox.ListIndex
  rst.FindFirst "petID = " & pPetListBox.List(indx, 0)
  'rst.FindFirst "petID = " & petList.ItemData(indx)
  If (pPetListBox.Selected(indx) And rst.NoMatch) Then
    rst.AddNew
    rst!personID = Me.ID
    rst!petID = pPetListBox.Column(0, indx)
    rst.Update
  Else
    If ((Not pPetListBox.Selected(indx)) And (Not rst.NoMatch)) Then
      rst.Delete
    End If
  End If
  rst.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Set pPetListBox = Me.msfPetListBox.Object
  FillPetListbox
End Sub

Private Sub msfPetListBox_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
'Private Sub petList_Click()
  UpdateLinkTable
End Sub
```

If you use the native access listbox you dont have to load the listbox content programmatically (FillPetListBox). Instead you can just set the rowsource-property to the pet-table. I think it is even possible to bind the MSForms.listbox to that table - but I didn't try it out (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Use a subform. Multiple checkboxes border on the insane :)

You need a table:

```
PersonID
PetID
```

PetID will be a combobox with a row source that lists possible pets. PersonID will be the link child and master field.

You do not need any code to do this.

Comment: The roblem with this approach is, that you could end up having one person having more than one relationships to the same class of pets. If that's ok then I would recommend this approach. What I see in your question is, that you want to just state "yep - I have that pet" or "no I don't have it". That would be a many-to-many-relationship which Access supports since acc2007 - but most professionals recommend not to use it since it relays on a hidden table and as soon as you want to access the data programmatically or use it in a non-access-solution it gets ugly.

Comment: yeah. i'm good with vba but i think access is trying to make my job "easier" but i now have to learn all this binding and subform stuff in the context of access just to make anything. i'd rather attack from behind but i bet it'd be a time saver in the end if i understood the wysiwyg components/controls access provides...  i feel like i almost made it harder somehow my defining my own joining id table to have a normalized database where i can see all the tables used... (that hidden joining table freaked me out a little when access fixed my many to many relationship)

Comment: both the combobox and list box do really have definite pro's and con's.... i'm not sure i really like either option.

Comment: If you don't want more than one relationship then simply set a unique compound key of Persion_Id, Pet_id on the table and you will not be able to add more than one instance

Comment: multiple check boxes... i just might be insane but i think i got it :o)